# Series expansion at infinity

Tags: limits, taylor-expansion, problem-solving, laurent-series

I am trying to find to generalize the limit that involves all rational functions such as $\sum_{n=0}^{l}\frac{{a}_{n}{x}^{n}}{{b}_{n}{x}^{n}}$. I believe the best way of generalizing all of them is using a limit expansion at infinity.

For example if we take $$\left({\left(\frac{x^2+5}{x+5}\right)}^{1.9}+{\left({x^2-5x+25}\right)}^{1.1}\right)^{23/22}-\left({\left({x-5}\right)}^{1.9}+{\left({x^2-5x+25}\right)}^{1.1}\right)^{23/22}$$

I think one way is to take the series expansion of this part of the limit and apply it to the second part..

$$\left({\left(\frac{x^2+5}{x+5}\right)}^{1.9}+{\left({x^2-5x+25}\right)}^{1.1}\right)^{23/22}$$

But that seems difficult so instead I tried to divide  ${\left({\left(\frac{1}{x^2-5x+25}\right)}^{1.1}\right)}^{23/22}$

$$\frac{\left({\left(\frac{x^2+5}{x+5}\right)}^{1.9}\left(\frac{1}{{x^2-5x+25}}\right)^{1.1}+1\right)^{23/22}-\left({\left({x-5}\right)}^{1.9}{\left(\frac{1}{x^2-5x+25}\right)}^{1.1}+1\right)^{23/22}}{{\left({\left(\frac{1}{x^2-5x+25}\right)}^{1.1}\right)}^{23/22}}$$

Then substituting $a={\left(\frac{x^2+5}{x+5}\right)}^{1.9}\left(\frac{1}{{x^2-5x+25}}\right)^{1.1}$ and $b={\left(x-5\right)}^{1.9}\left(\frac{1}{{x^2-5x+25}}\right)^{1.1}$

$$\frac{\left(a+1\right)^{23/22}-\left(b+1\right)^{23/22}}{{\left({\left(\frac{1}{x^2-5x+25}\right)}^{1.1}\right)}^{23/22}}$$

Then I took the laurent series of $\left(a+1\right)^{23/22}$ and $\left(a+1\right)^{23/22}$

But if I subsitiuted $a$ and $b$ back, (for the sake of shortcuts I denote them as $a(x)$ and $b(x)$).

$$\frac{\left({a(x)}^{23/22}+\frac{23{a(x)}^{1/22}}{22}+\frac{23}{968{a(x)}^{21/22}}\right)-\left({b(x)}^{23/22}+\frac{23{b(x)}^{1/22}}{22}+\frac{23}{968{b(x)}^{21/22}}\right)^{23/22}}{{\left({\left(\frac{1}{x^2-5x+25}\right)}^{1.1}\right)}^{23/22}}$$

But according to my graphing calculator and wolfram alpha this is not equal to...
$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left({\left(\frac{x^2+5}{x+5}\right)}^{1.9}+{\left({x^2-5x+25}\right)}^{1.1}\right)^{23/22}-\left({\left({x-5}\right)}^{1.9}+{\left({x^2-5x+25}\right)}^{1.1}\right)^{23/22}$

Is it possible to continue with my method or is their another approach that can generalize all rational functions?

Comment: This is $$F(x)=(f(x)+g(x))^a-f(x)^a$$ with $a=23/22$, $f(x)={\left({x-5}\right)}^{1.9}+{\left({x^2-5x+25}\right)}^{1.1}\sim x^b$ with $b=2.2$, and $g(x)=(x-5+h(x))^c-(x-5)^c$ with $h(x)=30/(x+5)\sim d/x$ for $d=30$ and $c=1.9$. Thus, $$g(x)\sim cx^{c-1}h(x)\sim cdx^{c-2}$$ and $$F(x)\sim af(x)^{a-1}g(x)\sim ax^{b(a-1)}cdx^{c-2}=acd.$$

Comment: @ Did did you approximate the first step.

Comment: What? $ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: Did you convert $\left(f(x)+g(x)\right)^a-{\left(f(x)\right)+\left(m(x)\right)}^a$ into $\left(f(x)+g(x)\right)^a-{\left(f(x)\right)}^a$

Comment: Never mind your right.

Comment: Step incorrect? Slow down? These are strong words to mathematicians. Are you using them at random or are they corresponding to some actual specific remarks you would have? In the latter case, please state these remarks precisely, otherwise I am not interested in more futile exchanges of this kind. In the specific situation at hand, you seem to have simply not read the definition of $f(x)$ in my first comment.

Comment: I apologize, I was wondering how you converted my limit into the form of your first step in your first comment. I will delete the offensive comments I made.

Comment: @Did your amazing. How long have been doing mathematics?

Comment: @Did How did you use the Taylor series to approximate $F(x)$ into $a{f(x)}^{a-1}{g(x)}$.

Comment: $$(t^a)'=at^{a-1}\implies(t+\epsilon)^a-t^a\sim a\epsilon t^{a-1}\quad(\epsilon\to0)$$

Answer (score 0):

*This is not an answer but it is too long for a comment.*

Did gave a very elegant answer and an efficient solution to approach this problem which looks to me as a nightmare.

Just for peronal fun, I decided to look at the asymptotics, considering $$A=\left(\left(\frac{x^2+5}{x+5}\right)^{19/10}+\left(x^2-5
   x+25\right)^{11/10}\right)^{23/22}$$ $$B=\left((x-5)^{19/10}+\left(x^2-5 x+25\right)^{11/10}\right)^{23/22}$$ and developed (funny work !) for infinite values of $x$. The fourteen first terms are identical in both expansions and, by the end, after so many cancellations, $$A-B=\frac{1311}{22}+\frac{1311}{484} \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{3/10}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{3/5}\right)$$

Comment: $$\frac{1311}{22}=\frac{23}{22}\cdot1.9\cdot30$$

Comment: @Did. Yes, I know. Be sure that I checked my result before anything else. I am sure that you did you read the first sentence in my anwser. Cheers.

Comment: @Arbuja. What I made was for ¨fun" ! What you must learn deeply is the approach Did gave in his answer. Cheers.